# In Xcode 10 can I restore Object library search bar in the inspector menu bar as it was before in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode9, developer-tools, xcode10

I was using Xcode 9 and in the recently updated version the Xcode 10, the Object Library search bar has been moved from bottom of the inspectors menu to the top of the navigation bar.

This is making me feel uneasy to use the object library search bar as I am used to search for the objects in object library search bar at the bottom of the inspectors menu as it was in the all those previous versions of the xcode.

So my question is: Is there any way to restore the object library search bar in the inspectors menu as it was in the previous version of the xcode?

In Xcode 10: The object library search bar is at the top
[image]

In Xcode 9: It was at the bottom of the inspectors menu
[image]

So how I can restore it like it was in xcode 9?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

I access it by clicking on the newly added button that took me almost 2 weeks to notice. I kind of like it better now.
[see where the button is located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7ywU.png).
There is also a short cut (command + shift + L), but I don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

In xcode 10 , Apple removed the object library to give more space to attribute inspector window , And to open Object Library press ***command+shift+L*** and the window of object Library will pop up you can either hit return or drag the object to the storyboard.

Comment: my question was can I bring back that previous gesture or can i bring back the object library search bar to the inspectors menu .... although apple has removed it from there... i mean is there any way to do so in the xcode 10?